# Using a UITabBar in a View-based app not working

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I have added a UITabBar to a View-based application, hooked up my View Controller as follows:

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController<UITabBarDelegate> {    

...

UITabBar *tabBar;

...

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBar *tabBar;
```

Inside my implementation file I have done this:

```
@synthesize tabBar;

- (void)tabBar: (UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
}
```

I went into IB and hooked tabBar up to File's Owner tabBar.

My problem: clicking on a tab bar item never fires off the didSelectItem method.  Am I missing or mis-doing a step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you set the delegate of the tabbar to self?

Comment: Thanks!  I can't believe I forgot this.  I will accept this answer ASAP.